# $L^4$-norm of a random variable. Why is it computed like that?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, supremum-and-infimum

Let's consider a random variable $\Delta(t)$ and consider that one has to compute:
 $$||\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}|\Delta(t)|||_{L^4}$$
It is computed like:

> $$||\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}|\Delta(t)|||_{L^4}=\mathbb{E}(\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}|\Delta(t)|^4)^{\frac{1}{4}}\tag{1}$$

However, shouldn't it be like:

> $$||\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}|\Delta(t)|||_{L^4}=\mathbb{E}(\color{red}{(}\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}|\Delta(t)|\color{red}{)}^4)^{\frac{1}{4}}\tag{2}$$

?
Could I consider $(1)$ the same as $(2)$? If so, why?

Comment: What is the difference? The two expressions  coincide.

Comment: Why do they coincide? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: $x^{4}$ is an increasing function on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Could you please explicit the reasoning underneath the statement "$x^4$ is an increasing function on $[0,\infty]$"? Which is the consequence of such a fact in relation to my question about differences between $(1)$ and $(2)$? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: @Strictly_increasing Increasing means preserves order, so suprema coincide

Comment: And so $\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}|\Delta(t)|^4=\color{red}{(}\sup\limits_{t\in[0,1]}|\Delta(t)|\color{red}{)}^4$? @Iwassuspendedfortalking

Comment: Yes. $|x|^4$ is maximized if and only if $|x|$ is maximized. If $f$ is an increasing function, and $x > y$, then $f(x) > f(y)$.

Comment: Very clear explanation, now I got it @BGM